# Tables randomly appear wiped on sails running on Heroku

Tags: javascript, sails.js, heroku-postgres

We have a sails.js app that uses waterline ORM to handle database stuff. It tends to work OK most of the time, except when (usually one of) our tables look like they are empty suddenly.

I wasn't able to track this down to any "obvious" problem, like our redeploying the server or something like that. It appears to happen at random times, not related to anything we do, and I don't think we have any code that's able to drop a table in db.

Our deployment is in "DEV" mode, so sails is able to change db model, but I can't think of a scenario where it would cause this problem.

We are also on free heroku and postgresql tiers and that's what's most suspicious to me.

I wasn't able to find any resource on heroku treating the DB differently except for row limits for free use, but I'd appreciate any insight into why this problem might happening, as well as some suggestions on how we can check if it's our fault.

Comment: Check in config/models.js the property "migrate". It should be to "safe". Also check inside config/local.js (if you have it) and config/env/development.js

Comment: I know, it is in dev mode, meaning our migrate property is not set to safe, but it is alter. Do you have an idea of why it would erase the table when there have been no changes to model or anything else for that matter?

Comment: No, nothing I can think of. Sure you don't have some query messed up, somewhere? some destroy() without conditions perhaps?

Comment: I just double checked it. I wasn't able to confirm that kind of suspicious empty destroy is there. I always pass at least { id: <expression> } to it, so there should be no issues. I will drill down on this, because I still can't believe we are doing everything right. If it was heroku issue I'd expect the table to get back on.

Comment: Well, why don't you change the migrate to safe. If it continues to happen you know the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: @DejanMaksimovic I would recommend you add query logging of some sort so you can truly assess if application code was at fault by cross-checking the last few queries run at the time data vanished. Also: if it happens randomly, I would wager it's a race condition rather than an explicit call to `drop` in the code. You can add the Heroku tag to this question if you truly think it's a Heroku issue, but statistics indicate 85% of all bugs stem from application code.

Comment: Thanks to both of you guys, I will get back to you on results of experiments we run on our side. @AkshatMahajan, can you elaborate on race condition possibility. One of the suspicious activities included something that might cause a race condition, but I don't get how that wouldn't be handled by db or sails.

Comment: @Dejan Maksimovic Without knowledge of your application architecture, it is difficult to say. For all I know, you could be batching delete requests but issuing writes incrementally, so that all of your deletes get processed in one shot while your writes are going through piecemeal. Again, query logging should help determine if application code is the culprit.

Comment: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/1058

We have found this gent that has the same issue. We are moving with changing to safe. @yBrodsky if you want to write an answer, I will gladly accept it once I confirm our problems are away.

Comment: Glad it worked. It was for little things like this that I moved away from waterline and then from sails altogether.